# How to migrate Joomla site Articles into Wordpress template?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

I want to convert a Joomla site articles into my Wordpress template. So,how this is possible ? Because I have never experience before article migration ... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Export Joomla articles through csv and upload to wordpress through csv. or you could try this http://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-joomla-to-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to copy information from the database and from the filesystem.

It may be easier to copy the full /images folder to wordpress or at least the subfolders that contain the article images in the very same position to make porting easier.

A convention: Joomla tables start with a random string, which the administrator chooses upon installation. It is referred to in Joomla code with "#*" so if my prefix were "jos" I would translate "#*_content" to "jos_content". Find out what your prefix is and replace as appropriate.

### Main content

Joomla stores articles in the table #__content.

For text, you want to grab the following columns:

```
title, alias, introtext, fulltext, metakey, metadesc
```

Just concat introtext and fulltext to get the full article.

Make sure there are no "internal" links, if the text of an article has a link to another article you might have to hand-fix it (or see the last section, moving urls).

### Images

The image urls embedded in your content should be fine if you copied the **images/** folder.

Now to the difficult part.  Joomla 2.5+ allow you to specify extra images which will be displayed in different views; those are accessible in Joomla's backend - edit article page.

Those are saved to the table field "images" in json in many formats.  Please note that they are seldom used, so you might want to glance over the contents of params quickly as you may be able to skip this step: this is the content you would see when no images are specified:

```
{"image_intro":"","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

If they are in use, you are out of luck.  You need to write a script to decode the json into a php object (json_decode).

### More info

Now for a few meta information you might not want to miss:

- state: 0 = unpublished, 1 = published, -2 = trashed
- catid: the id of the related #_categories table (which is hierarchical)
- created: the date the article was created
- created_by: the id of the author as specified in #_users; you might also want to check params (yet another json-encoded object) which contains the **author** property, where the author can write any arbitrary text to be used as their signature.
- publish_up: the date the article was published
- publish_down: although the article may be published, unless this is 0 or set in the future it won't show.
- urls: a json-encoded list of urls
- language: the default language for the article

## Moving urls

The Joomla SEF module is currently publishing your articles with a URL which most likely won't be the same as WordPress will use.  You might try to create such a menu structure that the urls look the same, or handle them in an .htaccess file with a simple rule as:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Joomla url (SEF or non-sef whichever you see in your Joomla site and / or is indexed in google)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=article&id=168&Itemid=67&lang=it$
#wordpress url
RewriteRule ^.*$ /some/path/title? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Please look it up it's very well documented elsewhere on stackoverflow, and a little beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: thnx Riccardo Zorn ...